# How does updating software work in code? Is it redownloading the application or checking certain files to see if they are different in size?

Tags: c#, auto-update

Does it go through each individual file, check if the amount of bytes in that file is different then the one in the server, and then replace that? Or does it just redownload the entire application recently if that app version is different to the server version?

C# examples of installation methods would also be helpful.

Comment: If you'd check each file individually, you'd want to compare their checksums, not just sizes. A file containing the text "kittens" isn't the same as a file containing the text "leopard".

Comment: Exactly which auto update mechanism are you thinking of here? An existing thing like ClickOnce (which, because it exists, is a question that can be answered) or a new nonexistent one that you haven't written yet (not a question that can be answered, may never be answerable if you ask like "what's the best way..")? Please edit your question to include the specific auto updater you're thinking of, or if you're fishing for "best ways" please think of a way of phrasing the question that can be answered with fact, not opinion

Answer (score 0):

This will be different for each kind update system. First of all the system or individual files should be versioned, so the system can know if a update is needed. You could also use hashes, but hashes do not tell what version is the latest, so you would need to keep relationships in some separate database.

The two major strategies for downloads are full download and patches. The downside with the later is that it has to be specific for both source and target versions. Most common would be some mix between the two, like distributing major changes as a full download, and smaller changes as patches. You might also want to allow a full download of the latest version to speed up new installations.

Here is an overview of the update formats microsoft uses

- [Full](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200210-00/?p=103426)
- [Delta](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200211-00/?p=103430)
- [Express](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200212-00/?p=103434)

Some applications, like games, may also have specialized container formats to minimize the need to move data around when updating. This can be important if you have large amounts of binary data, like images and models etc.